# VLOOKUP on a date returning REF error

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

I have a list of dates in a sheet (called TABLE) with the corresponding fiscal week next to the date.

On another sheet (ORDERS), I am trying to Lookup the date in the TABLE sheet and pull the corresponding week # in.

Here is my formula:

> `=VLOOKUP(J4,TABLE!A:A,2,FALSE)`

where J4 is the date in the ORDERS sheet, A:A has the dates listed and column B on TABLE has the week #.

I get a REF error... It seems like it tries to convert the date from "5/23/16" to "42513" for whatever reason. Help!

Comment: 42513 is the number of days since 1st January 1900 - which equates to 23rd May 2016.  The second argument in your VLOOKUP is only 1 column, at minimum this must be at least as many columns as  you're looking across - `TABLE!A:A` must be at least `TABLE!A:B` (but that would return an #N/A error.  Check your date is an actual date - if you add 1 to it does it return the following day or a #VALUE error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #REF error occurs because you have not selected enough columns. If you change your formula to =VLOOKUP(J4,TABLE!A:B,2,FALSE) it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Probably due to my inexperience with VLOOKUP.